# What does the symbol "⊇" mean?

Tags: normalization, database-theory, functional-dependencies

In the attached picture there's a symbol I don't understand. To understand additive functional dependency I need to know what the symbol means. Please advice?

[image]

It's the symbol where it says: "Suppose that X **⊇** Y and that..."

**⊇** = ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It [means](http://math.comsci.us/sets/symbols.html) "X is a superset of Y". The subset symbol is the same but flipped horizontally.

Answer (score 11):

This symbol is used in set theory to say that X is a superset of Y, ie. All elements of Y are contained within X. Note that X could be equal to Y in this meaning. Without the underlining on the symbol Y would be a strict subset of X meaning they cannot be equal

Comment: original answer had x and y the wrong way around. Corrected now

Answer (score 1):

A ⊇ B  -> Superset: A has the same elements as B, or more

A ⊃ B  -> Proper Superset: A has B's elements and more

for example:

A ⊇ B   ->  {1, 2, 3} ⊇ {1, 2, 3}

A ⊃ B   -> {1, 2, 3, 4} ⊃ {1, 2, 3}